# Kendo Treeview Angular - load complete dataset

Tags: kendo-treeview

By default Kendo treeview uses a lazy load for children nodes. That means until a node is expanded its children haven't been loaded and not available for lookup. Is there a way to force the tree to load the complete data?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `treeview.expand(".k-item");`

Comment: Will that load all children at once?